# Cursor returns id= 0 if folder has 1 element, XML file

Tags: android, xml, cursor

I try to find content:// adres of a created XML file with Cursor.

I do this with following code:

```
 public static String xmlFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + WiFiTransferService.FileServerAsyncTask.context.getPackageName()+ "/" + "variables" + ".xml";               

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        mFilesUri,
                        new String[]{MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID},
                        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?",
                        new String[]{xmlFilePath}, null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID));
                }

                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
```

The problem is that i get 0 id while I have one file in folder and get proper id (e.g. 3268) when i have 2 or more files. Quite strange behaviour and I have no idea what is causing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! I've created file in programme and stored it on SD Card, everything was ok but device didn't update its Data Base (DB). When I copy this file on my phone manualy, everything is added.

So what I needed to do is to add just created file to my phone DB programmaticly with following code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE,
                            FilenameUtils.getBaseName(xmlFilePath));
                    values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/*");
                    values.put("_data", xmlFilePath);
                    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);
```

Of course You have to add it before the Cursor starts. Code posted in question is written good, it just needs an update to DB.

Hope it will help either to avoid such mistake and to show how to extract XML File content:// path properly.